# What value should I send for `SameSite = None` and` Secure`?

Tags: iframe, samesite

Chrome update has given me great trouble
So far, I still haven't found anyone's answer in Chrome 80 that correctly answers SameSite issuess.
Leave the following questions for me and us.

In my html page, there is only  provided by YouTube.
However, in Chrome, 'cross-site requests if they are set with SameSite = None and Secure' are displayed.

What should I do?

I only did YouTube iframe, what value should I send cookie value and session value?
I want a direct solution.

A fake method like 'cross-site-cookie = name' doesn't help me.
I need a direct way to experience.

I want about php version <7.3 and I want to solve the problem with php or javascript or .htaccess etc.

[only youtube iframe tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4o7v.png)

Comment: Please post code with your question. HTML, and your server config file, what server are you using, does it work on other browsers, etc.

Comment: Could you reword your question to be more clear about what cookies (set by whom) you're asking about? Are you setting any cookies on your site? You cannot do anything about the cookies Youtube is setting. Also, try reading the documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite

Answer (score 0):

Chrome's [new cookie policy](https://blog.chromium.org/2019/10/developers-get-ready-for-new.html) requires applications to be served over HTTPS, if  some iframe content involves usage of [secure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_cookie) cookies.

This rule is enforced to disable unsafe requests accross sites, and reduce the risk of Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF).

You can read more about possible use cases in this post:

https://web.dev/samesite-cookie-recipes/